# Android - capture/suppress Home and EndCall buttons events?

Tags: android, key, keydown

If you ever tried to write a locker app on Android sure you meet this problem:

```
boolean mBackPressed = false;

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            mBackPressed = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            if (mBackPressed)
                unLock();
            break;
        default:
            mBackPressed = false;
            showMessage();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void showMessage() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Back + Menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

private void unLock() {
    this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    this.finish();
}
```

Seems like onKeyDown is filtering out all keys but "Back" and "Menu"...
*Well, it's not true!* Home button will still bring you Home screen and End Call button will run native Locker application!

Fellow's out there also claim it as a problem:
[How to listen from ENDCALL button](http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/ddc9b724f0aa4fce)
[problem With Home Back screen button](http://groups.google.co.jp/group/android-developers/msg/e5b3167d0c2768a5)
[Supressing Key presses in Activity, especially in Options Menu](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/7500657bd508170)
[Issue 4202: Feature Suggestion: permission for intercepting KEYCODE_CALL](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4202)

Do you know any workaround to block two those buttons?
Is the only way (as often) - *[write in C](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~omri/Humor/write_in_c.html)* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [capture the Back key quite easily](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html).

I don't think you'll be able to intercept the Home and End Call buttons.  If you could, this would allow a malicious application to prevent a user ever leaving it, effectively hijacking the phone.

An option for your application would be to write a replacement Home Screen using the  [`android.intent.category.HOME` Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#imatch).

Comment: Ugh... I've misplaced a couple buttons there... sorry for that. it's the Home and EndCall I need to handle.

Comment: Talking about malicious application, I believe user can alway reset phone or something like that. Sure it's a trouble but only once per malicious.

Comment: I think it's by design that you can't capture Home and EndCall so the user can always leave an application the same way.  One option for you might be to write a replacement Home Screen using the  `android.intent.category.HOME` Intent.